# What is the best method for creating a network packet struct/class in C#?

Tags: c#, networking

I'm wondering if there are any good guides or books that explain the best way to handle network packet communication in C#?

Right now I'm using a structure and a method that generates a byte array based on values of the structure.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Or even a better way?

```
public struct hotline_transaction
{
        private int transaction_id;
        private short task_number;
        private int error_code;
        private int data_length;
        private int data_length2;
```

...

```
        public int Transaction_id
        {
            get
            {
                return IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(transaction_id);
            }
            set
            {
                transaction_id = value;
            }
        }
```

...

```
        public byte[] GetBytes()
        {
            List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
            buffer.Add(0); // reserved
            buffer.Add(0); // request = 0

            buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Task_number));
            buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Transaction_id));
            buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(error_code));


            buffer.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Data_length));

            buffer.AddRange(subBuffer.ToArray());

            return buffer.ToArray(); // return byte array for network sending
        }
}
```

Beyond that is there a good guide or article on the best practice of parsing network data into usable structures / classes?

Comment: I probably should have clarified that I am dealing with an already established protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of [google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)?

> protocol buffers is the name of the
>   binary serialization format used by
>   Google for much of their data
>   communications. It is designed to be:
>
> small in size - efficient data storage
>   (far smaller than xml) cheap to
>   process - both at the client and
>   server platform independent - portable
>   between different programming
>   architectures extensible - to add new
>   data to old messages

Comment: Now, if only there was a C# implementation of that API which could be retro-fitted to an existing class simply by adding a few attributes... (cough) ;-p

Answer (score 2):

Well, rather than `GetBytes()`, I'd be tempted to use a `Write(Stream)`, in case it is big... but in the general case there are serialization APIs for this... I'd mention my own, but I think people get bored of hearing it.

IMO, `hotline_transaction` looks more like a `class` (than a `struct`) to me, btw.

Comment: +1 for class/struct distinction. Mutable structs are evil evil evil.

Comment: I'm not sure why I used a structure, it could easily be a class and actually after looking at the differences between structures and classes making this a class makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a `BinaryWriter` for this, and rather than returning `byte[]`, you should pass a `BinaryWriter` to the serialization code, i.e.,

```
public void WriteBytes(BinaryWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write((byte)0); // reserved
    writer.Write((byte)0); // request = 0

    writer.Write(Task_number);
    writer.Write(Transaction_id);
    writer.Write(error_code);

    writer.Write(Data_length);

    subBuffer.WriteBytes(writer);
}
```

You can easily wrap an existing `Stream` with a `BinaryWriter`. If you really need to get a `byte[]` somehow, you can use a `MemoryStream` as a backing stream, and call `ToArray` when you're done.