# Url capture from raw data packets?

Tags: network-protocols

We are capturing each network packet which is in this format (hex bytes). The problem is that we would like to get the url if it exist in the packet in the form of http://...... ? What is the best way to interpret it to capture the url? For now we are looking for http characters then process but where to end is another issue?

```
0000000    cf  fa  ed  fe  07  00  00  01  03  00  00  80  02  00  00  00
0000010    0c  00  00  00  28  07  00  00  85  80  01  00  00  00  00  00
0000020    19  00  00  00  48  00  00  00  5f  5f  50  41  47  45  5a  45
0000030    52  4f  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
0000040    00  00  00  00  01  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
0000050    00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
0000060    00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  19  00  00  00  78  02  00  00
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about the protocol? If you alreadly know there are unencoded ascii characters, maybe `strings` in gnu binutil can help.

Comment: @jokester well these are raw packets which I guess will be mostly tcp or udp right?

Comment: Have you read [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)?  To my knowledge, the text "http://" does not actually occur in the packets.  It simply tells the browser to use the HTTP protocol.  The browser will then establish a connection with the relevant HTTP server as defined by the protocol.  You'll need to sniff for packets that look like HTTP, and translate the destination IP back to a name - this might not be the same name as the original URL.

Comment: The name is in the `Host:` header of the HTTP protocol. It's mandatory, since the vast majority of websites are virtual hosted on shared ip addresses.

Comment: @R yes now we are able to capture the source ID but where is this host name is located you mean part of the packet too?

Comment: @R.. are you saying to look for this Host: stackoverflow.com\r\n but this does not give the full url right?

Comment: The rest of the url (the pathname) is in the initial `GET` line.

Comment: @R.. for e.g. I saw one sample Request Method: GET
Request URI: /gethired/js
Request Version: HTTP/1.1
Host: careers.stackoverflow.com\r\n
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329855/best-practice-generating-and-parsing-network-packets-for-a-known-protocol-in-c?rq=1\r\n. So what do you recommend to pick from here?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sound like you have the packets you are interested in, but you do not know anything about what the protocol is called, or its format (except that it isn't HTTP - if it were then the substring "http" that you say you find most likely would *not* appear).

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) understands a great many network protocols and would be a good start to help you find out what the protocol is and how the data in it is formatted.

If Wireshark doesn't recognise the protocol then you are probably on your own, unless you can give more details of where the packets came from and what they are for. The TCP port number to which the initial connection attempt is made is often a good clue. One thing that might help your final question is that strings are often terminated by a zero byte.

Comment: ok we are using a tool called pf_ring to capture raw packet header and we would like to know the urls which are being accessed from a particular network. Obviously the packets will have the url information? In addition to add yes we have been playing around with wireshark too. Hope now is clearer?

Comment: Are you saying Wireshark can't identify the protocol? Are there any protocol layers Wireshark can identify (e.g. UDP, TCP)?

Comment: I think wireshark can identify most of the protocol from what I notice? So the issue now how best to capture the right url from the raw packet what is your opinion on this?

Comment: I need you to tell me what protocol layers Wireshark has already identified before I can help you further. What is the highest level protocol that Wireshark identified for the packet you gave above? Is that the entire Ethernet frame? (Obviously not, so which part is it?)

Comment: so far what I notice is that only http protocol with get as the content on wireshark have the url information the rest of it mostly tcp packets does not have these information am I right here?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The HTTP GET command includes the URI. HTTP is a message-based protocol. It is usually sent over a TCP socket, which is stream-based. So when you look at an individual network packet you don't know whether it contains a single message, a fragment of a message, or even fragments from more than one message. That's why I asked the questions in my previous comment. If you can answer my questions I might be able to help you further.

Comment: the packet will definitely be individual packets which can be a fragment of a full message.

Comment: OK, I'll just say this then: Looking at an individual packet is not going to work. If this is the HTTP protocol over TCP (you still haven't said whether this is the case or not) then you need to capture the entire stream and parse it as an HTTP parser. You can distinguish the relevant packets by looking at the IP address and port number in the TCP header. Experiment with Wireshark to gain a better understanding of how this all works. Good luck.